# Installing Juniper network connect in 64 bit elementary OS

Tags: release-freya

I'm trying to make juniper network connect work on the 64 bit version of elementary OS.
Juniper requires 32 bit libraries.

Instructions for Ubuntu versions are:

For Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get –y install ia32-libs
```

For Ubuntu 13.10

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386
```

For Ubuntu 14.04

Install 32bit libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386
```

============================

I tried:

```
dpkg -i --force-architecture ./libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++6:i386.
(Reading database ... 120275 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_i386.deb ...
 De-configuring libstdc++6:amd64 (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ...
 Unpacking libstdc++6:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
 dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:i386 (--install):
 package libstdc++6:i386 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 cannot be configured  because libstdc++6:amd64 is at a different version (4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

But this looks like it didn't work.

Has anyone successfully installed this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Jamie Aylward

Answer (score -2):

Hi Have you tried the following mentioned on a ubuntu forum:

down vote
accepted
Solution for Ubuntu 11.10 or Later
Since Ubuntu 11.10 it shouldn’t be necessary anymore to use getlibs or some other workaround. The package system on 64 bit systems is now able to manage 32 bit libraries in parallel to the 64 bit libraries. You can even easily install complete applications with all their dependencies now!

Simply add :i386 to the name of the package you would like to install.

For example, I needed a 32 bit version of Java 7 and could install it (along with all its dependencies) simply by running:

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk:i386

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try. I did come across a solution of sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 which appeared to work although at the moment juniper doesn't recognise that they are installed - but will try your method. Much appreciated. Jamie Aylward